# Background Opacity for Table row <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to apply background color with opacity to the table row ,and not applying the opacity to the table data `<td>`, I am using the below style

```
 tr
    {
    background-color: #4682B4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    -moz-opacity:0.6;/* Mozilla */
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    }
```

It works fine with Internet explorer ,the opacity applies only to the table row not to the `<td>`, but with other browser the opacity also applies the `<td>` since it is attached to the `<tr>`.

Actually my mouseover event is

```
_cellMouseHover: function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            var row = $target.closest('tr');
            row.css({"background-color": "#4682B4",
                     "filter":"alpha(opacity=60)", /* IE */
                     "-moz-opacity":"0.6", /* Mozilla */
                     "opacity": "0.6","filter":"alpha(opacity=60)",
                     "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.6)", 
                    });
    },
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle for your code so that we can check the issue?

Comment: Table rows cannot have backgrounds; only cells do, and they inherit from the row.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: For my mouseover event I have applied css using jquery , so i have tagged with javascript and jquery , Blue Skies

Answer (score 3):

Dont use `"` with styles, please write it in following way:

```
tr
{
  background-color: #4682B4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* IE */
  -moz-opacity:0.6; /* Mozilla */
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

Comment: Sorry , i was using this style in my code behind using javascript , so i forgot to remove the quotes , but I didn't got my answer.

Comment: Hi! I did downvote your answer because your solution is not the best. You should speak about RGBA instead ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use RGBA for the `background-color` [instead of HEX](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/).

In your case :

```
tr {
  background-color:rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.6)
}
```

RGBA works the following way :
(red [0 - 255], green [0 - 255], blue [0 - 255], opacity [0 - 1]).