# jquery overlay after click, but dynamically over the clicked tr element

Tags: jquery

how can I place my overlay directly over the player name? in my table > tr

I thought using some dynamically coordinates of each clicked tr would be useful
but i dont know how...

the goal is, after the user clicked on a PLAYER name in the list to grey out the row with an overlay, AND after the user clicking again on the row the original version of my row will display (and delete the player on the field, but thats another topic i think)

here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcvcga8k/18/

i tried this:

```
$("table > tbody > tr").click(function() {

var overlay = $('<div id="overlay">');
$(this).append(overlay);
});
```

i already checked the manual and found functions like .width() and .height()
of jquery...

and i also know think, instead of .append() I have to use something else right?

but I need maybe a lil hint :(

thx for all your help!

greetz

Comment: you cannot insert/append div to tr,you have to do it inside td..so change it to $(this).find('td').append(overlay)

Comment: thanks for your help :)
ok i will try it, but i want to grey out the whole tr line... is that also possible with your suggestion?

Comment: not sure...this could be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063591/background-opacity-for-table-row-tr